# How to correct DoNotExposeGenericLists error C#

Tags: c#, list, collections, fxcop

I have the following method in DAL which accepts the model `OrderList` and returns a `List<OrderList>`

```
public List<OrderList> GetOrderList(OrderList orderList)
{
...
return new List<OrderList>();
}
```

When I analyze using FXCop, it's saying `DoNotExposeGenericLists` Error

FXCop is saying this as resolution

```
"Change 'List<OrderList>' in 'OrderRelatedDataAccess.GetOrderList(OrderList)' to use 
Collection<T>, ReadOnlyCollection<T> or KeyedCollection<K,V>"
```

How can I correct this?

My OrderList model is shown below

```
public int serialNumber { get; set; }
public int orderID { get; set; }
public int orderListID { get; set; }
public int productID { get; set; }
public int quantity { get; set; }
public long price { get; set; }
public string productName { get; set; }
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Code inside the method

```
List<OrderList> listOfOrderList = new List<OrderList>();
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sGetOrderListByOrderID", connection))
  {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", orderList.orderID);
    connection.Open();
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    int sno = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      long price = long.Parse(reader[4].ToString());
      listOfOrderList.Add(new OrderList()
      {
        serialNumber = ++sno,
        orderID = (int)reader[0],
        productID = (int)reader[2],
        quantity = (int)reader[3],
        price = price,
        productName = reader[5].ToString(),
       });
     }
   connection.Close();
 }
return listOfOrderList;
```

Comment: Where is "Phone.imageUrl"?

Comment: Can you show the code in that method or where you are using this method because I think anywhere you need generic object and you are using constant order list? If your are using Interface than please check that also what is the prototype there.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Please ignore it I will updated that line

Comment: In above code you are using List<Cart> and returning List<OrderList>

Comment: I am an idiot, I will edit my question once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right there in the FxCop message. Just change the return type to be `ICollection<OrderList>`, like so:

```
public ICollection<OrderList> GetOrderList(OrderList orderList)
{
    ...
    return new List<OrderList>();
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with my method definition. I am returning a collection!

Comment: @RandomUser I don't see a `Collection<T>` anywhere in your edit - can you clarify?

Comment: The tool FXCop is suggesting me to use `Collection<T>` instead of directly using `List<OrderList>` as a **Design Rule**. I am wonder how can I change my code to satisfy this!

Comment: @RandomUser No that is not so.. it just recommends you to not return a `List<OrderList>` from a public method, instead using `Collection<OrderList>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<OrderList>`, etc. You can read more here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx).

Comment: @metacubed, your code won't event compile since you cannot perform an implicitly cast a List<T> to a Collection<T>

Comment: @metacubed How can I achieve what you said? that was my first question or least that was what I wanted to ask..

Comment: Oops.. change that to be an `ICollection<T>` and you should be fine. See my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

In your case its best to change the method signature to use an IList instead of List

```
public IList<OrderList> GetOrderList(OrderList orderList)
{
 //get your data and build your list here
    return new List<OrderList>();
}
```

See the differences between ICollection and IList in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio)