# Using return type List<T> vs IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, list, resharper, ienumerable

I've created a function `foo` which creates and returns a type of `List<T>`. ReSharper is recommending that I change the return type to `IEnumerable<T>`. However, I know in the functions that call `foo` that some will want to access random elements in the List, so will need to call `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()` first.

Should I change the return type to `IEnumerable<T>`? Why?

Comment: It's not so much of a recommendation as a notification that you can. There are perfectly good reasons to do it and perfectly good reasons not to.

Comment: If the clients of your class want to do random access without writing, consider returning an `IReadOnlyList`, to indicate they are not supposed to modify it.

Comment: Or return an `ICollection<T>`.  It's usually best to return the least specific interface possible.

Answer (score 2):

If Resharper could know that some `foo` callers will want to access random elements in the List, it would not suggest you return `IEnumerable<T>`. As soon as only you have all picture, you should follow or not Resharper's suggestions, which are often very good though.

Answer (score 1):

Having a method return `List<T>` generally implies that it has constructed and populated a new `List<T>` instance for the benefit of the caller, the caller will then be free to modify that collection as it sees fit, and nothing else will modify the collection after that unless given a reference by the caller.  Methods returning arrays have similar expectations.  Having a method return a collection interface rather than a list or array type generally suggests that it might return a reference to an object that may either be lazily generated or reference data shared with other code, and that a caller that wants a mutable collection instance it can modify as well should feed the collection it receives to a method like `ToList` and use the collection returned by the latter method.

If the method is always going to construct and populate a new `List<T>` instance for the benefit of the caller, it should use a return type that indicates that (i.e. `List<T>` or `T[]`).  If it might benefit from being able to return an existing collection or a wrapper around one, returning some other type may be better.  Note that if callers would need to call `ToList` if given something other than `List<T>`, having the method return a `List<T>` itself would be a "win" even if a method which returns `List<T>` would have to make a copy of the list but a method returning some other type wouldn't.  In the event that a method would have to construct a new collection instance regardless of the return type, returning anything other than `List<T>` would be a loss if any callers would end up needing to call `ToList` as a result.

An alternative approach which is sometimes helpful is to have a class provide a method which accepts an `Action<T>` or something similar and invokes it on each item in the collection.  Code which wants to build a list containing all the items from multiple collections could then construct a delegate to append a passed-in item to a list and pass that delegate to each of the collections in question, avoiding the need to have each collection build a new `List<T>` instance for its items.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function that calls foo would do a `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()` it is most likely that **the purpose of that function is not only to iterate through your objects collection but also to process it (such as to sort it, to modify some elements, ...)**. IEnumerable is used for a collection of object that only needs to be iterated through. Therefore you should rather keep your List instead of changing it to IEnumerable. More usefull informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from ReSharper's documentation about the code inspection: [Return type can be `IEnumerable<T>`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReturnTypeCanBeEnumerable.Global.html):

> If a method returns a more generic type, it allows for more flexibility. On the one hand, caller methods can convert, if necessary, a value of `IEnumerable<T>` type into many other collection types or use it with LINQ. On the other hand, developers are likely to be able to change the method’s implementation without the need to change the return type.
>
> Also, returning a more general type may help in the future if you decide to change the return value to a more specific type, for example, `List<T>`: if callers expect `IEnumerable<T>`, they will be able to accept `List<T>`, but not vice versa.
>
> Note that such a replacement is not always possible, though. If methods of the derived type are used on the returned object anywhere in the solution, ReSharper will not issue this suggestion.

My opinion is that the type `IEnumerable<T>` carries strong [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation) semantics, which may incentivize callers to materialize the enumerable sequence to a `T[]` or a `List<T>`, in case they have to enumerate the sequence more than once. Materializing a sequence that is already backed by an underlying array or a list is wasteful, and for this reason I strongly disagree with this specific advice by ReSharper. I prefer returning an interface that is not typically associated with deferred execution, like `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IList<T>`.

Related Microsoft rule: [CA1851: Possible multiple enumerations of `IEnumerable` collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1851).