# how to select and convert the collection within an entity to SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My Model is given as:

```
public class Department
{
    // just keeping it relevant
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
public class Job
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to select the Jobs that belong to the specific department and convert them into Selectlist so that i can pass them to View.
What I have done in the controller is( yes i am hardcoding the id with value 1):

```
ViewBag.JobID = new SelectList( db.Departments.Where(x => x.ID == 1).Select(m => m.Jobs, "ID","Name");
```

But I am getting the following error, 
List does not contain a property with the name 'ID'

Comment: You don't have matching parenthesis - it should be `.Select(m => m.Jobs), "ID" ...` Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs returns a `List<Job>`, which of course does not have a property named ID. If you want to return a List, then you have to use SelectMany(x => x.Jobs).

Some other suggestions:

- Don't use List, instead use ICollection ([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio))
- Make your navigation properties virtual ([reason](http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/11/entity-framework-and-lazy-loading/))

Comment: thnx for suggestions. I am looking into it.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. The mistake I made is that I didn't include departmentID in the jobs class. Realized it after checking the tables in the database. So now I can directly select from db.jobs and save myself some hassle.