# Can't convert from Type ICollection to List with async

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I have the following code in a service:

```
var countriesTask = countryIds != null && countryIds.Any()
                                    ? this.dataContext.Countries.Where(c => countryIds.Contains(c.CountryId)).ToListAsync()
                                    : Task.FromResult(new List<Country>());
        var countries = await countriesTask;
```

I wanted to refactor out the dependency Datacontext by creating a RepositoryBase class:

```
IRepositoryBase:
    Task<ICollection<T>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match);

RepositoryBase:
    public virtual async Task<ICollection<T>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match)
    {
        return await this.DbContext.Set<T>().Where(match).ToListAsync();
    }
```

And then refactoring the above to:

```
   var countriesTask = countryIds != null && countryIds.Any()
                                ? this.countryRepository.FindAllAsync(c => countryIds.Contains(c.CountryId))
                                : Task.FromResult(new List<Country>());
   var countries = await countriesTask;
```

I'm getting a type conversion error (Can't convert from Type ICollection Country to Type List Country and my brain isn't working this morning. I know there is a ToListAsync that's probably causing the problem, but each time I change something, something else breaks! What do I do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need to do this:

```
var countriesTask =
    countryIds != null && countryIds.Any()
    ? this.countryRepository.FindAllAsync(c => countryIds.Contains(c.CountryId))
    : Task.FromResult<ICollection<Country>>(new List<Country>());
```

Basically both sides of the `?:` operator need to return the same type. Your code was trying to return `Task<ICollection<Country>>` & `Task<List<Country>>`. By making both return `Task<ICollection<Country>>` it should work fine.

Comment: im sure i tried that !?!...bad morning. needed a second pair of eyes. Thank you!

Comment: Can you return a IEnumerable<T> instead of a `ICollection<T>`? Then you can return `Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<T>())` and you don't need to create a new empty list.

Comment: Chose ICollection as the classes will be modified : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio

Comment: @MarkusGilli - Why do you want to avoid creating an empty list?

Comment: First I think it's better for readability. Because it just returns an existing empty enumerable it's  also better for performance and memory management. but when the collection will be modified this doesn't work...