# Why does Stack<T> not work as a navigation propery in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

I came across this by chance; I defined a navigation property as Stack; though the DB relation is created fine when I tried to query the entity using `Include` it says `A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'BreakAway.Destination' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Lodgings'.`
According to accepted answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio) as long as the navigation property type implements `ICollection` it should be fine. I just double check that `Stack<T>` does implement `ICollection`

The entities are:

```
 public class Destination
    {
        public Destination()
        {
            Lodgings = new Stack<Lodging>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte[] Photos { get; set; }
        public virtual Stack<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
    }

  public sealed class Lodging
    {
        public int LodgingId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public bool IsResort { get; set; }
        public decimal MilesFromNearestAirport { get; set; }
        public Destination Destination { get; set; }
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    }
```

Simple testing query:

```
        private static void QueryDestination()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var dest = context.Destinations.Include(d => d.Lodgings).First();
                Console.WriteLine("Destination Name: {0}",dest.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Lodging Name " + dest.Lodgings.First().Name);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to change the definition to `ICollection` like this `public virtual ICollection<Lodging> Lodgings`?

Comment: `Stack<T>` does not implement `ICollection<T>`

Comment: What @YacoubMassad said, `Stack<T>` implements `ICollection`, not `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Even if it worked it would be meaningless because the database rows are unordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation properties need to be of a type that implements `ICollection<T>` not `ICollection`. `Stack<T>` only implements `ICollection`.

Quoting from [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> A navigation property that represents the "many" end of a relationship must return a type that implements **ICollection, where T** is the type of the object at the other end of the relationship.

ICollection in the reference has a link that points to the MSDN reference for `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Can you provide a reference of this please?

Comment: ok thanks. Not sure why they didn't user ICollection<T> directly in the article which would make this a bit clearer. Thanks for the answer.