# Access count of related records of an entity Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two models:

```
public class HouseType
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<HouseModel> HouseModels { get; set; }
 }
```

and

```
public class HouseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
    public double StandardPrice { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HouseType")]
    public int HouseTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual HouseType HouseType { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<HouseUnit> HouseUnits { get; set; }
}
```

I am returning a JSON result, so as expected I cannot manipulate it in a view, because the display is handled by a javascript file that I made.

I am trying to retrieve the number of `HouseModel` that is contained by `HouseType`. I have tried:

```
db.HouseTypes.Select(h => new
 {
     HouseCount = h.HouseModels.Count()
  }).ToList();
```

But Entity Framework complains about it. How can I access the count of related records inside an entity? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? (you probably need `db.HouseTypes.Include("HouseModels").Select(....`

Comment: It says `specified type member not supported linq...` @StephenMuecke

Comment: can you try it with icollection instead of ienumerable ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Post that one as an answer. Worked like a charm. Than ks.

Comment: @Cyval  posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
public virtual ICollection<HouseUnit> HouseUnits { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public virtual IEnumerable<HouseUnit> HouseUnits { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain why ?

Comment: @Cyval Better check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, the trouble is that EF is trying to execute the `.Select()` statement on the db server but, of course, the db server does not know how to create a new object.

You first need to bring back the counts *then* create your objects so something like this should work better:

```
var listOfCounts = db.HouseTypes
    .Select(h => h.HouseModels.Count())
    .ToList()   
    .Select(c => new
    {
         HouseCount = c
    })
    .ToList();
```

in this example when the first `.ToList()` is executed the db needs only return a set of numbers (the counts of HouseModels in each HouseType) then we have a `List<int>` in local memory from which we can create our objects with the second Select statement.

As an aside...

It wasn't part of your original question but maybe you'd want to consider a dictionary rather than a list so you have some means of identifying which count of HouseModels belonged to each HouseType? in which case we could do something like:

```cs
Dictionary<int,string> houseModelCounts = db.HouseTypes
    .ToDictionary(h => h.Id, h => h.HouseModels.Count());
```

which would give a dictionary keyed with the HouseType Id with values for the count of HouseModels in each type. I don't know your context though so maybe unnecessary for you?