Using `IEnumerable<T> as a controller parameter in a database query
We are using linq2db. I think, while creating SQL query, it will enumerate twice ids, because ids is IEnumerable<T>. Am I right that enumeratiin of this ids will be twice and SQL query will be executed once?
I am not sure how I can test it and try to know whether it enumerates twice. Please, tell me how many times ids will be enumerated.
Having read this answer(Maybe I understood answer incorrecly), I believe SQL query will be executed once and ids will be enumerated twice?
[HttpGet]
[Route("persons")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAvailableAsync(IEnumerable<long> ids)
{
    IQueryable<PersonDto> query =
    from person in dbContext.GetTable<DbPerson>()           
    where ids.Contains(person.Id)  // here warning `Possible Multiple enumeration`
        || ids.Contains(person.DepartmentId) // here warning `Possible Multiple
                                             //  enumeration`
    select
        new PersonDto
        {
            Name = person.Name,
            Id = person.Id,
            DepartmentId = person.DepartmentId
        }).Distinct();

    return await query.ToListAsync()
}


In context of that answer yes. The question is why do you bind a controller parameter to IEnumerable? The other question is why do you receive the same IDs collection for different entities (Person, Department)?

@ZdeněkJelínek  The question is why do you bind a controller parameter to IEnumerable? what is the best practice? What type should it be?  Could you provide a link of IEnumerable should not be used and what type should be used, please? I want to apply best practices in my program.

Use ICollection<T> for example, those warnings will just go away.

@DavidG thank your reply! I know that if I use IList<T>, then this warning will dissappear.  But I am wondering if there is a rule what type of collection should be used in a controller or some guide lines or best practices? And  whether it is true that iteration of this ids will be twice and SQL query will be executed once?

I'd say you should use whatever collection type makes sense for your case as the consumer of the collection. If you need to enumerate twice or more, use a collection type that reflects that need so that you don't end up buffering (i.e. ToArray/ToList) something that the consumer already has as a collection anyway. And I suspect that at run-time, ASP will bind the IEnumerable to an array or List anyway. Also, IEnumerable implies that the sequence may potentially be large (hence we don't want to buffer it) but such approach would not result in a great query.

Also, if you only accept one collection of IDs, a consumer who wants people associated with Department ID = 4 will also get a person with ID = 4 regardless of their relationship with that department. So the client then needs to filter that data out. If you provided two separate parameters for the IDs, you could even use IEnumerable and be fine when it comes to the warning. However, such binding will probably be more complex. Whether the enumerables will truly be enumerated once is another story, though, as per Marc Gravell's answer. It will only make the warning go away.

@ZdeněkJelínek you are right! I see in debugger that ASP.NET binds IEnumerable to List. So is enumeration cheap? And warning is not dangerous for this IEnumerable?

you should definitly have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio in order to understand which interface to use when.

So is enumeration cheap? And warning is not dangerous for this IEnumerable? As long as ASP continues binding IEnumerable to a buffered collection, it is. However, I do think it is a better practice to be explicit about what's needed instead of hoping that the way consumers work will never change. So I would suggest using IReadOnlyCollection or more concrete type anyway, even if it won't cause problems at this time.

Since this is IQueryable<T>, we cannot say how many times it will be executed. Queryable expressions are typically inspected (at the Expression-tree level) and rewritten - in this case, most likely into SQL. We don't know the internals of that rewrite operation, so we cannot say how many times it evaluates ids - it might recognize the repetition and write this as a single parameter (or set of parameters) for both tests.
To find out how many times it is currently being iterated, you could write a custom enumerable and literally count the calls to GetEnumerator() - however, this is an implementation detail and may change.
If this was being evaluated as-written, for example via .AsEnumerable(), then: it will be enumerated twice (although note that Contains may also do type testing internally, so it is not actually treated as IEnumerable<T> internally, if it turns out to be a well-known type; you can see this here, for example, where it uses ICollection<T>.Contains when available).
If it matters how many times it is iterated: iterate it yourself once, for example via ToArray(), and use that snapshot in your LINQ query.
Tl;dr: the warning is valid.

Thank you for your answer! Is this double enumeration bad? I see in debugger that ASP.NET binds IEnumerable to List. So is this enumeration cheap? And warning is not dangerous for this IEnumerable because actually IEnumerable is List?

IEnumerable<T> in the general case is not guaranteed to be repeatable at all - it is not required that you can iterate it twice, and if you can: it is not guaranteed to provide the same data each time you iterate it. If it is actually a List<T>, then sure, it'll be repeatable, but if you know it is going to be List<T>, perhaps use List<T> as the parameter type, and the compiler warning will go away.

@MarcGravell the OP had asked an almost identical question already where ids was produced by an Enumerable.Range(). The OP hasn't tried to generate and inspect the SQL query as I suggested. That makes me suspect something else is at play, like an attempt to "stream" IDs from the client

@PanagiotisKanavos I've tried and saw SQL code generated by linq2db. And SQL code generated once. But I do not have a chance to profile and see how many times SQL code is sent to Oracle at the server side and executed at Oracle server.

There's no reason to assume it's sent twice, unless you call it in a loop. You don't need a profiler to inspect the queries though. You can configure logging for Linq2DB and log all everything, or use WithTraceLevel to control what gets logged
